# Background visible on the bottom of HTML page on mobile for video object-fit: cover

Tags: html, css, jekyll, bundle, liquid

I get a whitespace / blackspace /  background bar that appears on the bottom of my HTML page on mobile (on Chrome). The video-background and show-video states render with a gap on the bottom of the page-content. On mobile, the page is not taking up the full height of the screen when i use my bundle development server. Please help!

[Silly HTML whitespace Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lu092.jpg)

```js
// after content is loaded, wait two seconds to display video
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var videoContainer = document.querySelector(".video-background");
    videoContainer.style.display = "block";
  }, 2000); // 2000 milliseconds = 2 seconds
});
```

```css
/* General styling */
body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

/* Styles for the welcome section */
.welcome-page {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.welcome-container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 200px; /* Push it towards the bottom */
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;

  overflow-y: hidden;

  animation-name: expandAndShrink;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

/* Adjust the welcome container for mobile screens */
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .welcome-container {
    /* margin-top: 20vh; */
    /* recent- omit? */
    /* margin-top: 800px; */
    font-size: 48px;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
}

/* Adjust the welcome container for desktop screens */
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .welcome-container {
    margin-top: 0px; /* Apply a different margin for desktop */
    max-width: 600px;
  }
}

@keyframes expandAndShrink {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.25); /* Increase size */
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1); /* Back to original size */
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .welcome-content {
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}

.welcome-button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.46);
  transform: scale(12);
  transition: background-color 0.3s, transform 0.2s; /* Add this line to maintain transitions */
}

.welcome-button {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 10px rgba(10, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #fff; 
  padding: 1vh 4vw;
  border-radius: 80px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: background-color 0.3s, transform 0.2s;
  margin-top: 10px;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  animation-name: pulseAnimation;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes pulseAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(10, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 12px rgba(10, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(10, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .welcome-button {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}

.video-background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-background video {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: moveVideo 13s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes moveVideo {
  0% {
    object-position: 75% center;
  }
  100% {
    object-position: 23% center;
  }
}

.social-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.social-links .social-button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 252, 218, 0.532);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: transform 0.2s, border-color 0.3s;
}

.social-links .social-button:hover {
  border-color: rgb(130, 0, 0);
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.social-links .svg-icon {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  fill: rgba(0, 255, 221, 0.526)
}

 /* Hide the video container initially */
.video-background {
  display: none;
}

/* Show the video container with animation */
.show-video {
  animation: fadeIn 3s forwards;
}

/* Keyframes for fading in */
@keyframes fadeIn {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

/* Hide the video container initially */
.video-background {
  display: none;
}

/* Styles for the logo container */
.oc-logo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* Horizontally center content */
  align-items: center; /* Vertically center content */
  /* margin-top: 10vh; */
}

/* Styles for the logo image on mobile screens */
.oc-logo img {
  width: 70vw;
  height: 15vh;
  margin-bottom: 20vh;
}

/* Media query for desktop screens */
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  /* Adjust logo image styles for desktop */
  .oc-logo img {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 40vh;
    margin-bottom: 0vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="icon" href="{{ 'assets/images/robot.png' | relative_url }}">

</head>

<body class="welcome-page">
  <div class="welcome-container">
    <div class="video-background show-video">
      <video muted="true" autoplay loop>
        <source src="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/videos/FRCAuton.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>      
    </div>
    <div class="welcome-content">
      <div class="oc-logo"><img src="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/images/OCRobot.png" alt="OCRobotics"></div>
      <div class="social-links">
        <a href="https://github.com/OceanaRobotics" class="social-button"><svg class="svg-icon"><use xlink:href="/OceanaFRC/assets/minima-social-icons.svg#github"></use></svg></a>
        <a href="https://instagram.com/shelbyhschool" class="social-button"><svg class="svg-icon"><use xlink:href="/OceanaFRC/assets/minima-social-icons.svg#instagram"></use></svg></a>
        <a href="https://instagram.com/hhspirate" class="social-button"><svg class="svg-icon"><use xlink:href="/OceanaFRC/assets/minima-social-icons.svg#instagram"></use></svg></a>
        <a href="https://www.twitter.com/hartpirateposse" class="social-button"><svg class="svg-icon"><use xlink:href="/OceanaFRC/assets/minima-social-icons.svg#twitter"></use></svg></a>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/HartPublicSchools" class="social-button"><svg class="svg-icon"><use xlink:href="/OceanaFRC/assets/minima-social-icons.svg#youtube"></use></svg></a>
      </div>
      <a href="blog" class="welcome-button">welcome</a>
    </div>
  </div>  
  
</body>
</html>
```

If I swipe up quickly, the video takes the full screen size like I want. If I try to refresh, the background bar appears at the bottom of the page again and refresh does not occur. Then once the bar is at the bottom, I can refresh. I have stripped the code to only the video and this still happens. Tried display: block for video and did not work. Does not happen if I use incognito mode. Only for my bundle development server.